# Form to edit an object

Tags: zend-framework

I need to create a form that shows the attributes of an object to edit them.

I used symfony these last months and I had to do like this in the controller:

```
// retrieve the object $user from the database and then
$this->form = new UserForm($user);
```

What should I do in zf 1? create a constructor? is somethig already made about this?

Another question: how is usually called that operation?

Comment: Have you read any of the ZF documentation or tried the quick start tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

In ZF you would build a [Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.html) that is modeled off of your User object.  Call it the User Form.  Then when you need to use that form in CRUD operations, from the controller you would instantiate the form, retrieve your User object,  then use that object to populate the values of the form.

You could build that User Form inline on the controller... `$form = new Zend_Form...` or, as I usually prefer, write a class User_Form that extends the Zend_Form.  Makes your form's easier to manage and reuse.

Here is some example code...

I'm Assuming you can write the User_Form class, documentation should explain all that...  Lets just say its a form with a couple text elements for first name and last name.

On your controller...

```
$user = new User::Factory(array('id' => 1));

$form = new User_Form('myUserForm');

//keys would be the name of the form elements on the User Form
$formValues = array( 'firstName' => $user->getFirstName(), 
                     'lastName' => $user->getLastName());

$form->populate($formValues);
```

Then you just pass the $form to the view and render it.  Obviously would need to write more logic on the controller to handle first load / submit scenarios.  Hope this gets you started at least.  If you are looking for something that automagically generates the form from an object you pass it then you are out of luck.

Not sure what word you are searching for.  Perhaps 'Instantiate' or 'declare'?